# How to perform certain action based on the childsize of the DraggableScrollableSheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
 Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, left: 8),
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.2,
            minChildSize: 0.2,
            maxChildSize: 0.55,
            builder: (context, controller) {
              return SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: controller,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 400,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                      color: Colors.white70,
                    ),
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                                text: 'Swipe up',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 42,
                                    color: Colors.black38)),
                            WidgetSpan(
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 40,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.expand_less,
                                  size: 42,
                                  color: Colors.black38,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text('data'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text('data'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text('data'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text('data'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text('data'),
                    ]),
                  ),
                ),
                //),
              );
            }),
      )
```

The above code is DraggableScrollableSheet which contains column with list of widget and inside the column I added a sample text widget.I want to change [swipe up ^] into [swipe down (down arrow)] if the DraggableScrollableSheet child  size is greater than 0.35 else it will return back to swipe up ^. if anyone can help me achieve it, it will be great

Thank you for your time
[Swipe up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvMKl.png)
[Swipe down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhKrl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
class Sheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SheetState createState() => _SheetState();
}

class _SheetState extends State<Sheet> {
  bool isUp = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.cyan[50],
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0, .9),
            child: NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
              onNotification: (notification) {
                if (notification.extent > .35) 
                  setState(() {
                    isUp = true;
                  });
                else
                  setState(() {
                    isUp = false;
                  });
                return false;
              },
              child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                initialChildSize: 0.2,
                minChildSize: 0.2,
                expand: false,
                maxChildSize: .95,
                builder: (context, controller) {
                  return SafeArea(
                    child: ListView(
                      controller: controller,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                            color: Colors.white70,
                          ),
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: isUp ? 'Swipe up' : "swipe down",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 42,
                                    color: Colors.black38,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                WidgetSpan(
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 40,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.expand_less,
                                      size: 42,
                                      color: Colors.black38,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ...List.generate(
                            5,
                            (index) => Container(
                                  height: 100,
                                  color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(.5),
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(index.toString()),
                                )).toList(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


```
````

Comment: Thanks for your reply. regarding the code I implemented it but its stuck with swipe down even then child size is 0.2, it doesn't change to swipe up. I can add image of the GUI

Comment: can you add image that you want

Comment: sure, i added swipe down and swipe up images

Comment: can you check the upaded answer

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly later I will connect it to the main application and in case I faced any issue I will let you know